# Problem when using Simplify Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, simplify, generalization

I want to simplify district borders. As I got bad results when using polygons I converted those polygons into lines but I still have the same problem that I get new vertexes or corners I don't want.

Neither the `v.clean` nor the `v.generalize` tool will work for me to solve the problem.

This is my original border:
[image: Original border]

The output looks like that :
[image: simplified wrong border]

Comment: The output lines have certainly been simplified because they have fewer vertices.  What I find to be unusual is the multiple output lines, which leads me to question the input data; could it have been double-digitized?  Please describe your input data in more detail.

Comment: That's annoying. When it simplified the polygons it didn't recognize a shared border and instead simplified each polygon individually leaving slivers in the data. I'm not sure if QGIS has a way to automate fixing this. Does anyone know if there is a remove slivers tool for Q?

Comment: The input data looks good and didn't have any multiple lines. But I got it to work now, after chaning my PC I tried it again with v.clean before simplifying and suddently it worked properly. Thanks for your answers!